# Difference between wget versions

Tags: command-line, networking, wget

I have problem with wget behavior for 1.10 and later versions.

I am using wget to download a report from my app.

**version 1.10.2:**

```
>wget-1.10.2.exe --http-user=trader --http-passwd=trader http://192.168.1.222:8080/myapp/reports/FP201010271100 
--11:52:46--  http://192.168.1.222:8080/myapp/reports/FP201010271100
           => `FP201010271100.5'
Connecting to 192.168.1.222:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/csv]
    [ <=>                  ] 82,068        --.--K/s
11:52:46 (1019.65 KB/s) - `FP201010271100' saved [82068]
```

**version 1.11.4:**

```
>wget-1.11.4.exe --http-user=trader --http-passwd=trader http://192.168.1.222:8080/myapp/reports/FP201010271100
--2010-10-27 12:15:10--  http://192.168.1.222:8080/myapp/reports/FP201010271100
Connecting to 192.168.1.222:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://192.168.1.222:8080/myapp/spring_security_login [following]
--2010-10-27 12:15:10--  http://192.168.1.222:8080/myapp/spring_security_login
Reusing existing connection to 192.168.1.222:8080.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2010-10-27 12:15:10 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Do I need to add some parameter for version 1.11 and later?

### Update - Wireshark dump

**version 1.10.2:**

```
No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info
     17 13.756462   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1
     18 13.767667   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460
     19 13.767721   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0
     20 13.774991   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=189
     21 13.776327   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=0
     22 13.933894   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1420
     23 13.934039   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=1421 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1276
     24 13.934180   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=2697 Win=64240 Len=0
     25 13.935194   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=2697 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     26 13.945109   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=4045 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     27 13.945473   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=5393 Win=64240 Len=0
     28 13.948389   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [ACK] Seq=5393 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1420
     29 13.948443   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [ACK] Seq=6813 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1420
     30 13.948491   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=8233 Win=64240 Len=0
     31 13.948555   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [ACK] Seq=8233 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1420
     32 13.948604   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=9653 Win=62820 Len=0
     33 13.948650   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=9653 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1132
     34 13.954507   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=10785 Win=64240 Len=0
     35 13.955210   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=10785 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     36 13.972055   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=12133 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     37 13.972179   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=13481 Win=64240 Len=0
     38 13.973166   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=13481 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     39 13.973230   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=14829 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     40 13.973290   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=16177 Win=64240 Len=0
     41 13.975002   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=16177 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     42 13.975035   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=17525 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     43 13.975057   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=18873 Win=64240 Len=0
     44 13.975210   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=18873 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     45 13.975523   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=20221 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     46 13.975553   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=21569 Win=64240 Len=0
     47 13.983036   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=21569 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     48 13.983260   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [ACK] Seq=22917 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1420
     49 13.983290   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=24337 Win=64240 Len=0
     50 13.983324   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=24337 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1276
     51 13.983833   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=25613 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     52 13.983867   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=26961 Win=64240 Len=0
     53 13.984210   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=26961 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     54 13.984641   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [ACK] Seq=28309 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1420
     55 13.984672   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=29729 Win=64240 Len=0
     56 13.984705   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=29729 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1276
     57 13.984946   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=31005 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     58 13.984968   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=32353 Win=64240 Len=0
     59 13.986763   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=32353 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     60 13.986792   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [ACK] Seq=33701 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1420
     61 13.987044   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=35121 Win=64240 Len=0
     62 13.987088   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=35121 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1276
     63 13.987180   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=36397 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     64 13.987194   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=37745 Win=64240 Len=0
     65 13.993156   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [ACK] Seq=37745 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1420
     66 13.993181   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=39165 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1276
     67 13.993220   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=40441 Win=64240 Len=0
     68 14.013124   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=40441 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     69 14.014498   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [ACK] Seq=41789 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1420
     70 14.014539   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=43209 Win=64240 Len=0
     71 14.014574   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=43209 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1276
     72 14.014585   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=44485 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     73 14.014595   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=45833 Win=64240 Len=0
     74 14.015232   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=45833 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     75 14.015248   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=47181 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     76 14.015263   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=48529 Win=64240 Len=0
     77 14.015911   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=48529 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     78 14.016112   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=49877 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     79 14.016132   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=51225 Win=64240 Len=0
     80 14.016643   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=51225 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     81 14.016865   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=52573 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     82 14.016887   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=53921 Win=64240 Len=0
     83 14.017095   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=53921 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     84 14.018786   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [ACK] Seq=55269 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1420
     85 14.018823   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=56689 Win=64240 Len=0
     86 14.018981   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=56689 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1276
     87 14.018994   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=57965 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     88 14.019008   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=59313 Win=64240 Len=0
     89 14.024666   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [ACK] Seq=59313 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1420
     90 14.024685   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=60733 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1276
     91 14.024712   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=62009 Win=64240 Len=0
     92 14.025221   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=62009 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     93 14.026959   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=63357 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     94 14.027000   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=64705 Win=64240 Len=0
     95 14.027035   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=64705 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     96 14.027045   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=66053 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     97 14.027053   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=67401 Win=64240 Len=0
     98 14.027637   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=67401 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
     99 14.028162   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=68749 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
    100 14.028190   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=70097 Win=64240 Len=0
    101 14.028634   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=70097 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
    102 14.029058   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=71445 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
    103 14.029076   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=72793 Win=64240 Len=0
    104 14.029392   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=72793 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
    105 14.029819   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=74141 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
    106 14.029841   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=75489 Win=64240 Len=0
    107 14.030139   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=75489 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
    108 14.030510   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [ACK] Seq=76837 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1420
    109 14.030530   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=78257 Win=64240 Len=0
    110 14.030557   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=78257 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1276
    111 14.031644   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=79533 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1348
    112 14.031673   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=80881 Win=64240 Len=0
    113 14.032084   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [PSH, ACK] Seq=80881 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=1411
    114 14.032093   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [FIN, ACK] Seq=82292 Ack=190 Win=65535 Len=0
    115 14.032104   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=82293 Win=62829 Len=0
    116 14.040620   10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      kazaa > glrpc [FIN, ACK] Seq=190 Ack=82293 Win=62829 Len=0
    117 14.041564   172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > kazaa [ACK] Seq=82293 Ack=191 Win=65535 Len=0
```

**version 1.11.4:**

```
No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info
      1 0.000000    10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      mpc-lifenet > glrpc [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1
      2 0.021323    172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > mpc-lifenet [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460
      3 0.021379    10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      mpc-lifenet > glrpc [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0
      4 0.026476    10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          giFT     Response: GET /intraday/faces/reports/FP201010271100 HTTP/1.0
      5 0.026990    172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > mpc-lifenet [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=143 Win=65535 Len=0
      6 0.040137    172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             giFT     Request: HTTP/1.0 302 Found
      7 0.078133    10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          giFT     Response: GET /intraday/spring_security_login HTTP/1.0
      8 0.078741    172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > mpc-lifenet [ACK] Seq=237 Ack=278 Win=65535 Len=0
      9 0.097840    172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             giFT     Request: HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
     10 0.102113    10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      mpc-lifenet > glrpc [RST, ACK] Seq=278 Ack=1585 Win=0 Len=0
     11 0.103253    172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             giFT     Request: ipt src="/myapp/org/apache/myfaces/tobago/renderkit/html/standard/standard/script/tobago.js" type="text/javascript"
     12 0.103481    10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      mpc-lifenet > glrpc [RST] Seq=278 Win=0 Len=0
     13 0.103657    172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             giFT     Request: .startBody = new Date();
     14 0.103906    10.0.2.15             172.25.9.238          TCP      mpc-lifenet > glrpc [RST] Seq=278 Win=0 Len=0
     15 0.104174    172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > mpc-lifenet [RST, ACK] Seq=3779959295 Ack=278 Win=0 Len=0
     16 0.112019    172.25.9.238          10.0.2.15             TCP      glrpc > mpc-lifenet [RST, ACK] Seq=3779959295 Ack=278 Win=0 Len=0
```

Comment: Is the file downloaded with 1.10.2 correct?

Comment: Yes, the file downloaded with 1.10.2 is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `--auth-no-challenge` parameter.

> If this option is given, Wget will send Basic HTTP authentication information (plaintext username and password) for all requests, just like Wget 1.10.2 and prior did by default.

For details read [bug-description](http://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=221043)

Answer (score 1):

I just checked with wget 1.12 here on my machine and your parameters are fine. The output looks as if the server sends different data to both processes though:

The first directly gives you "200" (as in everything is fine) the second sends a "302" meaning redirect. The page it redirects to (http://192.168.1.222:8080/myapp/spring_security_login) doesn't exist though. I'd look at the server app first, because basic HTTP auth hasn't afaik changed in wget in quite a while (all my scripts still run and some of them are years old)

Comment: I added wireshark dump. The communication is different from start for each version.